# WSDL link for testing Web Service

Tags: web-services, webservices-client

I would like to know, Is there any `WSDL` link for web service which is running on `HTTPS` but not `HTTP` because I would like to test my client project whether it is working or not.
 Please send me the link as soon as possible because it is really important for the project.
Thanks!

Comment: What are you asking? I have no idea.

Comment: John Saunders, I would like to test web service by calling the Endpoint Reference, I have already tested unsecured HTTP link like http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx but now I would like to test with secure HTTPS link but the problem is I don't know any simple HTTPS wsdl link, so if you know any like which is few service so please refer me the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with this `WSDL`. Its from Amazon:

https://fps.amazonaws.com/doc/2008-09-17/AmazonFPS.wsdl

I haven't checked it but it is on HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks najus! the link you gave me, it is OK. But there are too much services in that links that I am not able to choose which service, I select and which value I pass. So if you know any simple and very few provided services then please share me. Although I have tested my client project with this simple unsecured wsdl link http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx and it worked fine. But now I would like to test with secure HTTPS wsdl link so please define me that link with very few services. Thanks!

Comment: @soewin u should give him +1 for giving True ans. :D